# JS assign array with objects values to object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, javascript-objects

I have an array with objects and an object. 
I want to use the array's every value parameters as the second object values.

here is the array:

```
attributes = [
        {key: 'Wifi', value: true},
        {key: 'Parking', value: false},
        {key: 'Pets', value: false},
        {key: 'Restaurant', value: false},
        {key: 'Bar', value: false},
        {key: 'Swimming pool', value: false},
        {key: 'Air conditioning', value: false},
        {key: 'Gym', value: true},
    ]
```

and here is the object:

```
data = {
        type: 'hotels',
        id: '11',
        attributes: {
                has_wifi: false,
                has_parking: false,
                has_pets: false,
                has_restaurant: false,
                has_bar: false,
                has_swimming_pool: false,
                has_air_conditioning: false,
                hsa_gym: false,
                name: '',
                main_image_src: 'https://placebear.com/300/300',
                meal_plan: '',
                user_id: '1',
                booking_id: '1',
                amount: '5000',
                currency: 'HUF',
                status: 'pending',
                stars: ''
        }
```

So i want to make the 'has_wifi' parameter to be equal with the 'Wifi', which is true in this case.
expected output:

```
...has_wifi: false,
                has_parking: true,
                has_pets: false,
                has_restaurant: false,
                has_bar: false,
                has_swimming_pool: false,
                has_air_conditioning: false,
                hsa_gym: true,...
```

Thanks!

I tried these:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         this.hotelservice.hotel.data.attributes[i] = this.hotelAttributes.data.attributes[i].value;
    }

this.hotelAttributes.data.attributes.forEach ((attr, index) => {
        this.hotelservice.hotel.data.attributes[index] = attr.value;
    })
```

Comment: so, what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried the simple for loop and forEach, but it only pushes the values to the object. like this: '0: true, 1: false...

Comment: @ZsoltMakrai Please show your attempt

Comment: @ZsoltMakrai Post the code that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just using the index of the array, not the adapted property name you want to create on the target object. Read key and value from the array and assign them in a loop to the object:

```
function keyFormat(k) {
    return 'has_'+k.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
}

for (var {key, value} of this.hotelAttributes.data.attributes)
    this.hotelservice.hotel.data.attributes[keyFormat(key)] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `attributes` and construct corresponding key by replacing spaces with underscores.

```
attributes.forEach(({key, value}) => {
    data.attributes[`has_${key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_')}`] = value
})
```

```js
attributes = [
        {key: 'Wifi', value: true},
        {key: 'Parking', value: false},
        {key: 'Pets', value: false},
        {key: 'Restaurant', value: false},
        {key: 'Bar', value: false},
        {key: 'Swimming pool', value: false},
        {key: 'Air conditioning', value: false},
        {key: 'Gym', value: true},
    ]

data = {
        type: 'hotels',
        id: '11',
        attributes: {
                has_wifi: false,
                has_parking: false,
                has_pets: false,
                has_restaurant: false,
                has_bar: false,
                has_swimming_pool: false,
                has_air_conditioning: false,
                hsa_gym: false,
                name: '',
                main_image_src: 'https://placebear.com/300/300',
                meal_plan: '',
                user_id: '1',
                booking_id: '1',
                amount: '5000',
                currency: 'HUF',
                status: 'pending',
                stars: ''
        }
}

attributes.forEach(({key, value}) => {
    data.attributes[`has_${key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_')}`] = value
})

console.log(data.attributes)
```